# Eigenvalues of $UV^T$ in SVD decomposition

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

After performing a singular value decomposition (SVD) of a real square matrix $A$,

$$A=USV^T$$

1. How to prove that the absolute value of all eigenvalues of $UV^T$ are one?
2. Is there any relation between the eigenvalues of $UV^T$ and those of $A$?

Comment: What do you mean by *the absolute value of ... are one?*

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net What is meant is *"The absolute value of each eigenvalue equals 1"*. Of course $A$ must be square, otherwise te SVD is still defined, but not the eigenvalues of $UV^T$.

Comment: If $\lambda=a+ib$, then the absolute value is $\rm{abs(\lambda)}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$

Comment: A late hint could be that all (non-real) complex roots to a real coefficiented polynomial equation come in conjugate pairs.

Comment: Eigenvalues of $UV^T$ are one in absolute value and eigenvalues of $A$ can be arbitrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Q=UV^T$, then $Q$ is orthogonal, since $QQ^T=UV^TVU^T=I$.

Now, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $Q$ for the eigenvector $v$, then $Qv=\lambda v$, hence $v^Hv=v^HQ^HQv=\bar\lambda\lambda v^Hv$ implies that $|\lambda|=1$. Note that $Q^T=Q^H$ since $Q$ is real.

Comment: And regarding my second question, there is not a direct relation, or there is?

Comment: @AJHC None that I know of - which does not mean there is none. However, bear in mind that all matrices that have identical $U$ and $V$ but different singular values will have the same value of $UV^T$. This implies that matrices with widely different eigenvalues have the same $UV^T$.